# Fatfree php (v3.6.5) dependency injection CONTAINER

Tags: dependency-injection, containers, fat-free-framework

Does anybody have a simple example of usage?

https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/quick-reference#CONTAINER page 
seem to me not really explanatory, but generally i need to figure a nice way to auto-inject `$db_connection` object just when/where needed, e.g.
In class's `beforeRoute()` method for smooth route resolving

Comment: `$f3->set('DB', new \DB\SQL(...));` and `$f3->get('DB')` where you need it.. for real DI,.. you can use any PSR-11 compatible DI-Container.. you just have to set its classname to the CONTAINER variable.. more insights in here: https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree-core/pull/221

Comment: All right, to keep it simple, while resolving routes:
First concern to require 'DB' only if no db-connection is present (left over from previous connects). So, is it nice to:
$f3->route('GET /', function($f3) {$f3->get('DB'); 'Cons::struct'}); or better get 'DB' within Cons's __construct() method ?
I just wantto  make sure that connection is really necessary (no persisted from past) prior to including/injecting.
So, maybe indeed above way is good to go (simplest and safe) with PDO argument setting: ATTR_PERSISTENT => FALSE ?

Answer (score 1):

When porting selfoss to use DI, I chose Dice as suggested in the docs you linked. I set up the container to use only a single shared instance of the DB class and pass it the connection string:

```php
$f3 = Base::instance();

$dice = new Dice\Dice;

$host = $f3->get('db_host');
$database = $f3->get('db_database');
$dsn = "pgsql:host=$host; dbname=$database";

$dbParams = [
    $dsn,
    $f3->get('db_username'),
    $f3->get('db_password')
];

$dice->addRule(DB\SQL::class, [
    'constructParams' => $dbParams,
    'shared' => true,
]);

$f3->set('CONTAINER', function($class) use ($dice) {
    return $dice->create($class);
});
```

Then F3 will use the Dice container to create classes so controllers and any of their dependencies will be passed the instantiated dependencies in the constructor:

```php
namespace daos;

class Items {
    private DB\SQL $db;

    public function __construct(DB\SQL $db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function fetchAll() {
        $entries = $this->db->exec(…);
        …
    }
}
```

See the [selfoss source code](https://github.com/fossar/selfoss/blob/2eac971772a2fcee8282f5a0a416d9324c757e33/src/common.php#L74-L228) for a full example of how to configure the dependency container.

Answer (score 0):

So, i've opted for singleton:
// Database class

```
class DB
{
    private static $_instance = null;
    private $dbconn = null;

    // config files should better be located in more secure dir
    const DB_HOST = '127.0.0.1';
    const DB_NAME = 'my_db_name';
    const DB_USER = 'my_db__user';
    const DB_PASS = 'my_db_passw';
    const CHARSET = 'utf8';
    const DB_PREFIX = '';
///////////////////////////////////
private function __construct () {

    $this->dbconn=new DB\SQL(
      'mysql:host='.self::DB_HOST.';port='.self::DB_PORT.';dbname='.self::DB_NAME,
      self::DB_USER,
      self::DB_PASSW,
      $options = array(
          \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
          \PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => FALSE)
        );
}

////////////////////////////////////
public static function getInstance() {
        if (!self::$_instance) {
        self::$_instance = new DB();
      }
        return self::$_instance;
}

//////////////////////////////////
public function connect() {
    if ($this->dbconn) {
        echo 'Hooray - 1st stage connected!';
    return $this->dbconn;
    }
    else echo '<br>Sad enough, no connection :(((';
}
/////////////  /////////////////  ////////////////////

    private function __clone() {  }
    private function __wakeup() {  }

}
```

Comment: // main controller:   
$f3->route('GET /yoo', function($f3){ 
  $connection = $f3->call('f3pdo::getInstance')->connect(); 
  echo '<hr>'; 
  $result = $connection->exec('SELECT * FROM MyDBTable'); 
  //...etc
    }); 
    
 Or better use entity class's beforeRoute() {*->connect()}

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for dummyness, i've just discovered for myself built in \Prefab class (to be extended for singletons), so the above DB connection i'd rather do LIKE%:

```
class DB extends \Prefab {

    private $dbconn;
// ..then just do connection thing

public function connect() {
//////
}
```

}